# Why is this true: $1- (1-1/n)^{\varepsilon n} \leq \varepsilon + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function, exponentiation

In my lecture notes, the following is written:

$$1- (1-1/n)^{\varepsilon n} \leq \varepsilon + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$$

as $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ and $n$ some fixed constant (non-negative integer),
but I do not understand why.

Everything I get is

$$1-(1-1/n)^{\varepsilon n} \leq e^{-(1-1/n)^{\varepsilon n}}$$

but I am not able to get to the statement.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is strange to use $O(\varepsilon^2)$ as $n \to +\infty$.

Comment: yes, you are completely right. Thanks for the hint. I am wrong, it is not $n \rightarrow \infty$ but $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$, so my ideas from above do not make sense at all.

Comment: What's strange as well is this: what does it mean to use an inequality with Bachmann's notation ($\mathcal O$). Given it is a sort notation for boundedness modulo a constant factor, it is meaningless.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with Bachmann's notation, we call it Landau notation. I tried to google it but did not find anything about it, but maybe it is the same. In my lecture, we use $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(g(x)), f(x)\leq \mathcal{O}(g(x))$, as well as $f(x) \in \mathcal{O}(g(x))$ interchangeably.

Comment: Are there any further restrictions on $n$?

Comment: The only restriction we impose on $n$ is that it must be a non-negative integer.

Answer (score 1):

The power series for an analytic function is an asymptotic series as well, so we can say that $\exp \delta \sim 1+\delta + \mathcal O(\delta^2)$ as $\delta \to 0$.

Applying this to your expression yields 
$$ 1 - (1-1/n)^{\epsilon n} = 1 - \exp(\epsilon n \log(1-1/n)) \sim -\epsilon n \log (1-1/n) + \mathcal O(\epsilon^2)~~. $$

Note that $-n\log(1-1/n) > 1$ for each $n>1$, and in fact tends to 1 as $n\to\infty$. In particular, if $n$ is constant, this is also a constant. I'm not clear on which definition of asymptotic notation you're using, but perhaps this information is enough to conclude the desired result?

Comment: I am not completely sure whether I get what you mean, because we have $exp( - \varepsilon)$ and not $exp (\varepsilon)$ and also not exactly. 
So what you would propose is:
$1-(1-1/n)^{\varepsilon n} \sim 1- e^{-\varepsilon } \sim 1- (1- \varepsilon + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon ^2) )= \varepsilon + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$?
I do not see why the first $\sim$ is valid, however..

Comment: I used $(1-1/n)^{\epsilon n} = \exp ( \epsilon n \log (1-1/n) )$; the negative arises in subtracting the whole thing from 1. Perhaps it is confusing because I am using the entire exponent in the latter case as my 'epsilon'; I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you did. Thanks a lot. But I am afraid it is still not what I am looking for and somehow confuses me as it seems to contradict what I aim to prove.

Comment: Referring to your comment above, if you use $f(x)=\mathcal O(g(x))$ and $f(x)\le\mathcal O(g(x))$ interchangeably, you're (likely) not trying to find an actual inequality involving $n$; you're just making an asymptotic statement about the order of the expression in powers of $\epsilon$, ignoring constants. In particular, if you wanted that inequality in $n$, as this answer shows, it wouldn't hold.